# Clojure- Remove entries from customized set

Tags: clojure

I'm a bit new to Clojure and was wondering if anybody can assist me here.
I'm trying my hands on clojure's persistent data-structures.I have 2 hashset like below example.

`(def a #{[1 345] [2 346] [3 347]})`

`(def b #{1 2})`

So,I want to remove '**b**' from '**a**'.I am expecting output like below:

`#{[3 347]}`

I've looked for quite a bit to try and get an understanding of how to do this, but so far I'm just puzzled.I've tried playing around with remove/tried to convert 'a' into a map.but couldn't get the expected result
.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one way:  Build a map from `a` and use `dissoc` to remove the keys found in `b`.

```
> (set (apply dissoc (into {} a) b))

#{[3 347]}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution, though I must confess I like the above one more:

```
(set (filter #(not (contains? b (first %))) a))

#{[3 347]}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using specter:

```
(setval [ALL (comp b first)] NONE a)
```